# On which site can I ask about DDoS attack technology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which site can I ask about DDoS attack technology?

Which site is about traffic attack and the traffic problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) deals with these topics. Like on all Stack Exchange sites, your question must be *specific*; please read their [help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking. You have enough reputation to chat in their general chatroom, [DMZ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz), where people might be willing to help you formulate your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, by the way, can you tell me the DMZ meaning?

Comment: It's a reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)